# How to do the mean relative error for different groups after groupby?

Tags: python, aggregate, mean

I am doing a project that deals with a large dataset. However, now I wanted to make a mere comparison and I can't find how I can do it. Simply put to a simpler problem, my problem is as follows. I have 3 different columns, and 6 rows:

```
A   B   C
g   1   2 
h   2   1
j   3   3
h   3   3
g   4   3
j   5   4
```

The first thing I wanted to do was calculate B's average, median and mode taking into account A's group. So I did this way, and so far so good:

```
aggregations_proc = {'C': { 'Mean_proc': 'mean', 'Median_proc': 'median',
                                  'Mode_proc': lambda x: x.mode()}}
groupy_proc = df.groupby('A', as_index=False).agg(aggregations_proc)
```

However, my goal now was simply to create a new column representing the calculation of the mean relative error for each of the rows between B and the mean of C, given that the mean varies for each group.
For example, for the first line, the relative error would be:
(Group g average - 1st row B value) / Group g average
However, for the second line, it would already be
(Group h average - 2nd row B value) / Group h average
And for the 3rd line
(Group j average - 3rd row B value) / Group j average
But this applies to a much larger dataset.

Any help will be very welcome!

[UPDATE]

Here's my new code. I think everything is working, but I guess theres some error about the mode. The error is " Columns must be same length as key". The code is the following:

```
aggregations_diag = ('mean', 'median', lambda x: x.mode().iloc[0])
groupy_diag = df.groupby('A', as_index=False) 
['B'].agg(aggregations_diag) 

def absolute_error_diag(x): 
stats = ['mean', 'median', lambda x: x.mode().iloc[0]]
avg = groupy_diag.loc[x['A'], stats] 
return (avg - x['B'])

# Columns for the absolute error of each row
columns_names_diag = ['ae_diag_mean','ae_diag_median','ae_diag_mode']

df[columns_names_diag] = df.apply(absolute_error_diag, axis=1)

[MAE_diag_mean, MAE_diag_median, MAE_diag_mode] = 
df[columns_names_diag].sum()/len(df['ae_diag_mean'])
```

Comment: It might help if you create another chart of what you want it to look like because I am having trouble visualizing the end product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `aggregations_proc` function in the question does not aggregate over column `B`. One way to do the aggregation could be:

```
aggregations_proc = ('mean', 'median', lambda x: x.mode().iloc[0])
groupy_proc = df.groupby('A', as_index=False)['B'].agg(aggregations_proc)
```

Notwithstanding that, `apply()` can be used in combination with `df` and `groupy_proc`. The function for calculating mean relative error could be:

```
def mean_rel_error(x): # x is a row of df
    avg = groupy_proc.loc[x['A'], 'mean'] # to find avg, locate 'mean' col in the row corresponding to the value of col A 
    return (avg - x['B']) / avg
```

The function call would look like:

```
df['mre'] = df.apply(mean_rel_error, axis=1)
```

Hope this helps. For more efficiency, you could consider creating a dictionary of means only and modify the `mean_rel_error()` function

---

UPDATE:

Here is the code to calculate the mean absolute error that worked for me:

```py
l = [["g",1,5], ["h",2,2], ["j",3,9], ["g",3,5], ["j",4,3], ["h",5,1], ["g",11,1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=["A", "B", "C"])

aggregations_proc = ('mean', 'median', lambda x: x.mode().iloc[0])
groupy_proc = df.groupby('A', as_index=False)['B'].agg(aggregations_proc)
groupy_proc.columns = ['mean', 'median', 'mode']


def mean_rel_error(x):
    stats = ['mean', 'median', 'mode']
    avg = groupy_proc.loc[x['A'], stats] 
    return (avg - x['B'])

columns_names_diag = ['ae_diag_mean','ae_diag_median','ae_diag_mode']

df[columns_names_diag] = df.apply(mean_rel_error, axis=1)
[MAE_diag_mean, MAE_diag_median, MAE_diag_mode] = df[columns_names_diag].sum()/len(df['ae_diag_mean'])


print(MAE_diag_mode)
-> -2.2857142857142856
```

Comment: Oh yes! I completely understood! Thank you very much for your help, really! Just one question, what would be the dictionary for?

Comment: @bonaqua dictionary for storing means, meant for quicker lookups. It could be of the format `{x:mean(x)}` where `x` is an element of column `A`.

Comment: @bonaqua does this answer your question? If yes, please feel free to accept the answer! Cheers!

Comment: I updated my question with new code! However now I have an error. I don't know if you can help me, but do you have any idea why is that wrong?

Comment: @bonaqua I don't see anything wrong with the code, except for the `stats = ['mean', 'median', lambda x: x.mode().iloc[0]]`. Try renaming the last column of `groupy_diag` to a suitable name like `mode` and use that name instead of the lambda function in the `absolute_error_diag()` function. So the new assignment would look like `stats = ['mean', 'median', 'mode']`

Comment: if I switch for "mode", it works, but why shouldn't I use "lambda x: x.mode.iloc[0]"? If I use "mode", the MAE_diag_mode will is zero.. So I think that something may not be right

Comment: @bonaqua Using a lambda function in stats assignment generated extra columns when I tried to run the changed code. Also, `MAE_diag_mode` returned a non-zero values. See the updated answer.